# After running through my algorithm fine, my array returns as all zeros

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I've spent a long time finally getting my algorithm to invert Laplace transforms and live plot them to work, but unfortunately, although it seems to run fine within the function, it continuously just plots zeros!

[image]

I've wasted so much time getting this thing to work, and now I have no clue what could be wrong. So forgive me but I think I'll have to post the whole thing.

The equation this is based on is a series-integral and it iterates until the series converges. However, it converges super slowly so I used Aitken's delta-squared method to speed the whole thing up. The goal is to populate array `y` with each Aitken's iteration from 0.000001 to 10 and then compare the estimation' integral with the previous iteration's if a random point in the former is close enough to the latter. This loops until the integrals have a difference of less than 0.01 or a set amount of iterations is reached (~30000).

This happens for 6 equations simultaneously using parallel processing. The graph live plots all 6 (in blue) compared to each of the actual equations they're converging towards (in red) using matplotlib.

For debugging, I basically tried putting a bunch of print statements everywhere in the `f_u` function to see what was going on. Everything looked like it was going fine. But in the `__main__` function and `plot` functions when I did the same, I was getting all zeros for the same array. I thought it was a local vs. global issue so I put `global y` in the `plot` and `f_u`, with no luck.

To execute this, you're gonna need all the packages in the import statement, including numba. You can remove the `@jit` decorations on the Laplace functions if you don't want numba, but it will be sloooooow.

Here it is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib import animation
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad, simps
from scipy.special import jv
import math
import random
import datetime
import multiprocessing as mp
from numba import jit

start = datetime.datetime.now()     # Record time start

# Initialize plot
style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2)
((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4), (ax5, ax6)) = axes

plt.autoscale(enable=True)

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.label_outer()

# Initialize variables
gamma = np.array([np.nan, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1])    # Bromwich contour parameter for each equation
num = 6     # Number of equations to be processed in total
n = 0   # Repetition constant for equation 3, set to either zero or 1 (diverges at 1)
max_count = 1000   # Number of data points in x and y
epsilon = 10 ** -40     # Minimum number to divide by in Aitken's iteration
err = 10 ** -4    # Maximum difference in y to trigger comparison in closing()
max_err = 0.01    # Maximum difference in integrals computed in closing() to end iteration process

x_0 = 0     # Set first integral to 0 for now
result = np.zeros(7)    # Vector to store Aitken's iteration for closing() comparison
previous = np.zeros(7)     # Vector to store iteration before Aitken's for closing() comparison
end = np.zeros(7)     # Vector to store end conditions -- running = 0, ended = 1

u, step = np.linspace(0.000001, 10, max_count, retstep=True)    # Initializing x values

y = np.empty([num, 4, max_count])     # Initializing y values -- form is y[equation number][iteration in Aitken's][x value]
y_denom = np.empty([num, max_count])    # Initializing array to store Aitken's denominator values for each equation
x_iter = np.empty([num, max_count])    # Initializing array to store Aitken's iteration as starting point for next iteration

def printer(num, k):    # Prints the equation number, iteration and y value at 10
    if num == 1:
        print(str(num) + "    " + str(k) + "    " + str(y[0][3][max_count-1]) + "\n")
    elif num == 2:
        print(str(num) + "    " + str(k) + "    " + str(y[1][3][max_count-1]) + "\n")
    elif num == 3:
        print(str(num) + "    " + str(k) + "    " + str(y[2][3][max_count-1]) + "\n")
    elif num == 4:
        print(str(num) + "    " + str(k) + "    " + str(y[3][3][max_count-1]) + "\n")
    elif num == 5:
        print(str(num) + "    " + str(k) + "    " + str(y[4][3][max_count-1]) + "\n")
    elif num == 6:
        print(str(num) + "    " + str(k) + "    " + str(y[5][3][max_count-1]) + "\n")

def plot1():    # Plots estimation 1 (blue) and actual equation 1 (red)
    global y
    ax1.clear()
    line1, = ax1.plot(u, y[0][3][0:max_count])
    ax1.plot(u, np.sin(u), 'tab:red')
    return line1,

def plot2():    # Plots estimation 2 (blue) and actual equation 2 (red)
    global y
    ax2.clear()
    line2, = ax2.plot(u, y[1][3][0:max_count])
    ax2.plot(u, np.heaviside(u, 1), 'tab:red')
    return line2,

def plot3():    # Plots estimation 3 (blue) and actual equation 3 (red)
    global y
    ax3.clear()
    line3, = ax3.plot(u, y[2][3][0:max_count])
    ax3.plot(u, np.cos(2 * np.sqrt(u)) / np.sqrt(np.pi * u), 'tab:red')
    return line3,

def plot4():    # Plots estimation 4 (blue) and actual equation 4 (red)
    global y
    ax4.clear()
    line4, = ax4.plot(u, y[3][3][0:max_count])
    ax4.plot(u, np.log(u), 'tab:red')
    return line4,

def plot5():    # Plots estimation 5 (blue) and actual equation 5 (red)
    global y
    ax5.clear()
    line5, = ax5.plot(u, y[4][3][0:max_count])
    ax5.plot(u, np.heaviside(u - 1, 1) - np.heaviside(u - 2, 1), 'tab:red')
    return line5,

def plot6():    # Plots estimation 6 (blue) and actual equation 6 (red)
    global y
    ax6.clear()
    line6, = ax6.plot(u, y[5][3][0:max_count])
    ax6.plot(u, jv(0, u), 'tab:red')
    return line6,

def animate(i):     # Plots all equations, used to live-update graph
    ln1, = plot1()
    ln2, = plot2()
    ln3, = plot3()
    ln4, = plot4()
    ln5, = plot5()
    ln6, = plot6()
    return ln1, ln2, ln3, ln4, ln5, ln6,

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p1(omega, u, k):      # Equation 1, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma[1]

    f1 = a * (1 / (a ** 2 + (b + 1) ** 2) + 1 / (a ** 2 + (b - 1) ** 2)) * np.cos(omega)
    return f1

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p2(omega, u, k):      # Equation 2, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma[2]

    f2 = a / (a ** 2 + b ** 2) * np.cos(omega)
    return f2

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p3(omega, u, k):      # Equation 3, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma[3]

    f3 = np.e ** (-a / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)) * (a ** 2 + b ** 2) ** (1 / 4) * np.cos(
        (math.atan2(b, a) + 2 * n * np.pi) / 2) * np.cos(b / (a ** 2 + b ** 2)) / (
                np.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2) * (np.cos((math.atan2(b, a) + 2 * n * np.pi) / 2) ** 2 + np.sin(
                    (math.atan2(b, a) + 2 * n * np.pi) / 2))) * np.cos(omega)
    return f3

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p4(omega, u, k):      # Equation 4, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma[4]

    f4 = -(a * np.log(a ** 2 + b ** 2) + a * np.e) / (a ** 2 + b ** 2) * np.cos(omega)
    return f4

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p5(omega, u, k):      # Equation 5, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma[5]

    f5 = a * (np.e ** (-a) * np.cos(b) - np.e ** (-2 * a) * np.cos(2 * b)) / (a ** 2 + b ** 2) * np.cos(omega)
    return f5

@jit(nopython=True, cache=True)
def f_p6(omega, u, k):      # Equation 6, Laplace form
    b = (omega + k * np.pi) / u
    a = gamma[6]

    f6 = np.sqrt((a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) ** 2 + (2 * a * b) ** 2) * np.cos(
        (math.atan2(2 * a * b, a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) + 2 * n * np.pi) / 2) / (
            ((a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) ** 2 + (2 * a * b) ** 2) * (
                np.cos((math.atan2(2 * a * b, a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) + 2 * n * np.pi) / 2) ** 2 + np.sin(
                    (math.atan2(2 * a * b, a ** 2 - b ** 2 + 1) + 2 * n * np.pi) / 2) ** 2)) * np.cos(omega)
    return f6

def closing(result, previous, num, k):    # Checks for convergence. If so, adds each term to f_0 and ends process
    if abs(result - previous) < max_err:
        diff = abs(result - previous)

        print("Equation " + str(num) + " converges to " + str(diff) + " with " + str(k) + " iterations." + "\n")

        if num == 1:
            for i in range(max_count):
                y[0][3][i] += f_0(num)
            end[1] += 1
            return 1
        elif num == 2:
            for i in range(max_count):
                y[1][3][i] += f_0(num)
            end[2] += 1
            return 1
        elif num == 3:
            for i in range(max_count):
                y[2][3][i] += f_0(num)
            end[3] += 1
            return 1
        elif num == 4:
            for i in range(max_count):
                y[3][3][i] += f_0(num)
            end[4] += 1
            return 1
        elif num == 5:
            for i in range(max_count):
                y[4][3][i] += f_0(num)
            end[5] += 1
            return 1
        elif num == 6:
            for i in range(max_count):
                y[5][3][i] += f_0(num)
            end[6] += 1
            return 1
    else:
        print("Equation " + str(num) + " has not yet converged.\n")
        return 0

def f_0(num):     # Initial integral in the series. Added at end after closing() convergence test
    for i in range(max_count):
        if num == 1:
            x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
                f_p1, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]
        elif num == 2:
            x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
                f_p2, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]
        elif num == 3:
            x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
                f_p3, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]
        elif num == 4:
            x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
                f_p4, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]
        elif num == 5:
            x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
                f_p5, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]
        elif num == 6:
            x_0 = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * quad(
                f_p6, 0, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], 0))[0]

    return x_0

def f_u(u, num):    # Main algorithm. Here, the summation integrals iterate
    global y, result, previous    # Forces retrieval of from global of these arrays? (attempt to debug)
    k = 1   # Number of iterations

    for i in range(max_count):  # First overall series iteration (initial 1st)
        if num == 1:
            y[0][0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p1, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
        elif num == 2:
            y[1][0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p2, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
        elif num == 3:
            y[2][0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p3, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
        elif num == 4:
            y[3][0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p4, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
        elif num == 5:
            y[4][0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p5, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
        elif num == 6:
            y[5][0][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                f_p6, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]

    for j in range(10000):   # Iteration loop. Goes until closing() or k = ~6000 for each equation
        if j > 0:
            for i in range(max_count):  # Sets the first iteration (out of 3 for Aitken's) equal to the previous Aitken's or the first iteration if j = 0 (1st)
                if num == 1:
                    y[0][0][i] = x_iter[0][i]
                elif num == 2:
                    y[1][0][i] = x_iter[1][i]
                elif num == 3:
                    y[2][0][i] = x_iter[2][i]
                elif num == 4:
                    y[3][0][i] = x_iter[3][i]
                elif num == 5:
                    y[4][0][i] = x_iter[4][i]
                elif num == 6:
                    y[5][0][i] = x_iter[5][i]
            else:
                k += 1

        for i in range(max_count):  # Second iteration for Aitken's (2nd)
            if num == 1:
                y[0][1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p1, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 2:
                y[1][1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p2, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 3:
                y[2][1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p3, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 4:
                y[3][1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p4, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 5:
                y[4][1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p5, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 6:
                y[5][1][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p6, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]

        k += 1

        for i in range(max_count):  # Third iteration for Aitken's (3rd)
            if num == 1:
                y[0][2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p1, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 2:
                y[1][2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p2, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 3:
                y[2][2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p3, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 4:
                y[3][2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p4, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 5:
                y[4][2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p5, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]
            elif num == 6:
                y[5][2][i] = 2 * np.e ** (gamma[num] * u[i]) / (np.pi * u[i]) * (-1) ** k * quad(
                    f_p6, -np.pi / 2, np.pi / 2, args=(u[i], k))[0]

        k += 1

        for i in range(max_count):  # Aitken's delta-squared method iteration using the previous 3 (4th)
            if num == 1:
                y_denom[0][i] = (y[0][2][i] - y[0][1][i]) - (y[0][1][i] - y[0][0][i])

                if abs(y_denom[0][i]) < epsilon:
                    print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                    return 9

                y[0][3][i] = y[0][2][i] - ((y[0][2][i] - y[0][1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[0][i]
            elif num == 2:
                y_denom[1][i] = (y[1][2][i] - y[1][1][i]) - (y[1][1][i] - y[1][0][i])

                if abs(y_denom[1][i]) < epsilon:
                    print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                    return 9

                y[1][3][i] = y[1][2][i] - ((y[1][2][i] - y[1][1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[1][i]
            elif num == 3:
                y_denom[2][i] = (y[2][2][i] - y[2][1][i]) - (y[2][1][i] - y[2][0][i])

                if abs(y_denom[2][i]) < epsilon:
                    print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                    return 9

                y[2][3][i] = y[2][2][i] - ((y[2][2][i] - y[2][1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[2][i]
            elif num == 4:
                y_denom[3][i] = (y[3][2][i] - y[3][1][i]) - (y[3][1][i] - y[3][0][i])

                if abs(y_denom[3][i]) < epsilon:
                    print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                    return 9

                y[3][3][i] = y[3][2][i] - ((y[3][2][i] - y[3][1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[3][i]
            elif num == 5:
                y_denom[4][i] = (y[4][2][i] - y[4][1][i]) - (y[4][1][i] - y[4][0][i])

                if abs(y_denom[4][i]) < epsilon:
                    print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                    return 9

                y[4][3][i] = y[4][2][i] - ((y[4][2][i] - y[4][1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[4][i]
            elif num == 6:
                y_denom[5][i] = (y[5][2][i] - y[5][1][i]) - (y[5][1][i] - y[5][0][i])

                if abs(y_denom[5][i]) < epsilon:
                    print("Denominator too small to calculate. Exiting...\n")
                    return 9

                y[5][3][i] = y[5][2][i] - ((y[5][2][i] - y[5][1][i]) ** 2) / y_denom[5][i]

        k += 1
        printer(num, k)

        rand = random.randrange(0, max_count)   # Setting random number for x value

        # Comparison between y at random x in Aitken's vs the previous iteration. If close enough, triggers closing()
        if num == 1:
            if abs(y[0][3][rand] - y[0][2][rand]) < err:
                result[num] = simps(y[0][3][0:max_count], u, dx=step)   #Integrates Aitken's iteration (4th)
                previous[num] = simps(y[0][2][0:max_count], u, dx=step)    #Integrates integration before Aitken's (3rd)
                c1 = closing(result[num], previous[num], num, k)
                if c1 == 1:
                    break
        elif num == 2:
            if abs(y[1][3][rand] - y[1][2][rand]) < err:
                result[num] = simps(y[1][3][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                previous[num] = simps(y[1][2][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                c2 = closing(result[num], previous[num], num, k)
                if c2 == 1:
                    break
        elif num == 3:
            if abs(y[2][3][rand] - y[2][2][rand]) < err:
                result[num] = simps(y[2][3][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                previous[num] = simps(y[2][2][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                c3 = closing(result[num], previous[num], num, k)
                if c3 == 1:
                    break
        elif num == 4:
            if abs(y[3][3][rand] - y[3][2][rand]) < err:
                result[num] = simps(y[3][3][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                previous[num] = simps(y[3][2][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                c4 = closing(result[num], previous[num], num, k)
                if c4 == 1:
                    break
        elif num == 5:
            if abs(y[4][3][rand] - y[4][2][rand]) < err:
                result[num] = simps(y[4][3][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                previous[num] = simps(y[4][2][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                c5 = closing(result[num], previous[num], num, k)
                if c5 == 1:
                    break
        elif num == 6:
            if abs(y[5][3][rand] - y[5][2][rand]) < err:
                result[num] = simps(y[5][3][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                previous[num] = simps(y[5][2][0:max_count], u, dx=step)
                c6 = closing(result[num], previous[num], num, k)
                if c6 == 1:
                    break

        for i in range(max_count):  # Setting current Aitken's iteration to first iteration
            if num == 1:
                x_iter[0][i] = y[0][3][i]
            elif num == 2:
                x_iter[1][i] = y[1][3][i]
            elif num == 3:
                x_iter[2][i] = y[2][3][i]
            elif num == 4:
                x_iter[3][i] = y[3][3][i]
            elif num == 5:
                x_iter[4][i] = y[4][3][i]
            elif num == 6:
                x_iter[5][i] = y[5][3][i]

    # If iteration limit reached, sets process closing condition to 1 and returns to main
    end[num] = 1
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0

    # Define and begin processes, one for each equation
    p1 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 1))
    p2 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 2))
    p3 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 3))
    p4 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 4))
    p5 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 5))
    p6 = mp.Process(target=f_u, args=(u, 6))

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()
    p4.start()
    p5.start()
    p6.start()

    # While any equation is running, update and show the plot every second
    while end[1] != 1 or end[2] != 1 or end[3] != 1 or end[4] != 1 or end[5] != 1 or end[6] != 1:
        animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=True)
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.show(block=False)
        plt.pause(1)

    # Joining and closing each process when complete
    p1.join()
    p1.terminate()
    p2.join()
    p2.terminate()
    p3.join()
    p3.terminate()
    p4.join()
    p4.terminate()
    p5.join()
    p5.terminate()
    p6.join()
    p6.terminate()

    end = datetime.datetime.now()   # Record time end

    print("Runtime: " + str(end - start))

    # Updates and plots final result
    animate(i)
    plt.show()

    exit(0)
```

Hope you can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would advise you to add comments to the code or provide an explantation of the steps, not the math but the code. Also, please tell us the what you have discovered in the time spent debugging this code so we don't have to eliminate the same causes.

Comment: You should also provide details for executing the code and show the plots you speak of

Comment: My bad, just added some comments and and the 2x3 plot. To execute, you just run it and it spits out the equation number, overall iteration number and y value at x = 10 to the console and opens a plot that auto-updates. Cheers, and Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy new year! I think you may have an issue with shared memory in multiprocessing. The main thread has an array which is initialized to all zeros, the children are calculating values in their memory space but this memory space is not shared with the main thread. You could look into shared memory semantics.